# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

Tags: php, mysqli, timeout

Recently we started seeing intermittent MySQLi connection errors from php:

```
E_WARNING: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
```

It does not happen often; three or four times a day, and we average a connection every 10 seconds. We do set the MySQLi timeout option to 5 seconds.

```
 mysqli_options($db_connection, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

Five second should be plenty of time to connect though. Any idea what could be happening? This is a remote MySQL server hosted on Google compute cloud *(i.e. not local to php-fpm)*, though the latency from the php-fpm servers to the MySQL server is decent 55ms.

Comment: Are these connections long lived (10 minutes) or short connections to perform just a few queries?

Comment: Short lived, less than 1 second.